# Como configurar o CURL do PHP para não aguardar a resposta

Tags: php, libcurl

Pessoal estou em um projeto onde tenho o seguinte cenário.

Utilizo um cron onde o PHP vai disparar mensagens para um determinado webhook, porém este webhook será de terceiros.

Estou utilizando o CURL, porém ao fazer alguns testes, caso o webhook não tenha um retorno, o CURL fica processando até estourar o tempo limite.

O que preciso é disparar a mensagem, e após o disparo, passa para a próxima mensagem. O que não pode é o disparo ficar travado até que haja alguma resposta do webhook.

Segue o exemplo de CURL que estou utilizando

```
$options = array();
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = "url do webhook";
$options[CURLOPT_HEADER] = false;
$options[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
$options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
$options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = array("mensagem");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

#Envia a requisicao e verifica o retorno
if (($result = curl_exec($ch)) === FALSE) {
    $retorno = false;
} else {
    $retorno = true;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Espero ter sido claro e agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Acredito que essa resposta aqui do site possa te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php

Comment: Eu utilizei CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT e CURLOPT_TIMEOUT e deu certo. Obrigado.